# How to catch NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications, nsworkspace

I've trying to get callback after file operation performing, but I can't catch NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification posting.

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(finderDidFileOperation:) name:NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification object:[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] performFileOperation:fileOp source:source destination:item.fullPath files:objects tag:&tag];
```

> object:nil

also didn't works and

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] addObserver:self forKeyPath:NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

too.

What I've doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key here is that the `NSWorkspace` posts the notification to its notification center, not the global default one.  From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Before this method returns, it posts an NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification to the NSWorkspace object's notification center.

Try registering for the notification with that notification center instead, like this:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] 
    addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(finderDidFileOperation:) 
    name:NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification 
    object:[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]];
```

Comment: I think `[NSWorkspace notificationCenter]` will not work as `notificationCenter` is an instance method. Should probably register with `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]`.

Comment: Wow what a gotcha. Almost all Notifications just use the defaultCenter usually... ugh.